# Mailkit - replace text in Html part

Tags: c#, mailkit

will appreciate any Help on this one.

I am trying to replace text in an email template using Mailkit. The issue is that in Mailkit there is at least a text part and and Html part.

I can get then set the text part using code such as:
`var textPart = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().FirstOrDefault();`

I can get the htmlbody using
`var htmlPart = message.htmlBody`
but once I modify it I do not know how to set the htmlpart to the message's htmlBody.

My code so far:

````
               FileStream sr = new FileStream(fileLocation + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
               message = MimeMessage.Load(sr);
               sr.Close();             
               //Get the text Part
               var textPart = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().FirstOrDefault();
               
               //Get the HtmlBody
               var htmlPart = message.HtmlBody;

               string regexPattern;
               string regexReplacement;
               Regex regexText;
               foreach (var replaceSet in replaceArray)
               {
                   regexPattern = "#" + replaceSet["Key"].ToString() + "#";
                   regexReplacement = (string)replaceSet["Value"].ToString();
                   //bool test = Regex.IsMatch(docText, regexPattern);
                   if (regexReplacement != "")
                   {
                       regexText = new Regex(regexPattern);
                       textPart.Text = regexText.Replace(textPart.Text, regexReplacement);
                       //Set, modify the text part
                       htmlPart = regexText.Replace(htmlPart, regexReplacement);
                   }
               }
               
               try
               {
                   message.WriteTo(fileLocation + "\\output\\" + fileName);
               }
               catch (Exception Ex)
               {
                   result = Ex.Message;
                   return BadRequest(result);
               }```
````

Comment: you could try with BodyBuilder object  -https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/1e34019d85219b97cc42efeea981838b83a71f66/Documentation/Examples/BodyBuilder.cs#L15

Comment: Thanks. That would mean I would need to to create a new email I think. In my case I need to use an existing email template.

Comment: I think just you need to rebuild the body  `message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably work:

```
// Get the text Part
var textPart = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsPlain);
var htmlPart = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsHtml);

string regexPattern;
string regexReplacement;
Regex regexText;

foreach (var replaceSet in replaceArray)
{
    regexPattern = "#" + replaceSet["Key"].ToString() + "#";
    regexReplacement = (string)replaceSet["Value"].ToString();
    //bool test = Regex.IsMatch(docText, regexPattern);
    if (regexReplacement != "")
    {
        regexText = new Regex(regexPattern);
        textPart.Text = regexText.Replace(textPart.Text, regexReplacement);
        //Set, modify the text part
        htmlPart.Text = regexText.Replace(htmlPart.Text, regexReplacement);
    }
}
```